# Json Decode Twitch Api PHP

Tags: php, json, twitch

I am trying to get propriety of Json Decoded string of twitch tv

```
$hue = file_get_contents('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/?channel=starladder1');
$hue = json_decode($hue);
print_r($hue->display_name);
```

but it doesnt work tryed almost everything please help

Comment: $hue->display_name doesn't exist

Comment: already did it, but i want to get data of display_name not the full one check the json decoded, it exists.

Comment: print_r($hue->streams[0]->channel->display_name); although the stream index may vary

Comment: worked thanks bumper

Answer (score 2):

Try following code:

```
<?php
    $hue = file_get_contents('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/?channel=starladder1');

    $hue1 = json_decode($hue, TRUE);

     foreach ($hue1 as $data)
        {
         foreach ($data as $datas) {

        echo ($datas['channel']['display_name']."<br/>");

             }   
        }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

the reason why it is not working is because you try to access "display_name" directly without analyzing the structure of the object.

Try this:

```
print_r($hue->streams[0]->channel->display_name);
```

You see that streams begins with an "[" which means that its elements are accessed like an array

Your object really looks like this, and this helps you to understand the structure better:

```
 {
        "streams":[{
            "_id":10954982848,
            "game":"Dota 2",
            "viewers":11918,
            "_links":{
                "self":"https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/starladder1"
            },
            "preview":{
                "small":"http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_starladder1-80x50.jpg",
                "medium":"http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_starladder1-320x200.jpg",
                "large":"http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_starladder1-640x400.jpg",
                "template":"http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_starladder1-{width}x{height}.jpg"
            },
            "channel":{
                "_links":{
                    "self":"http://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/starladder1",
                    "follows":"http://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/starladder1/follows",
                    "commercial":"http://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/starladder1/commercial",
                    "stream_key":"http://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/starladder1/stream_key",
                    "chat":"http://api.twitch.tv/kraken/chat/starladder1",
                    "features":"http://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/starladder1/features",
                    "subscriptions":"http://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/starladder1/subscriptions",
                    "editors":"http://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/starladder1/editors",
                    "videos":"http://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/starladder1/videos",
                    "teams":"http://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/starladder1/teams"
                },
                "background":null,
                "banner":null,
                "display_name":"starladder1",
                "game":"Dota 2",
                "logo":"http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/starladder1-profile_image-557367f831a49ebb-300x300.png",
                "mature":false,
                "status":"NewBee vs LGD-Gaming 1:0 @ WEC Lan-Finals Day 2 by v1lat",
                "url":"http://www.twitch.tv/starladder1",
                "video_banner":"http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/starladder1-channel_offline_image-c29311bb34830472-640x360.png",
                "_id":28633177,
                "name":"starladder1",
                "created_at":"2012-03-01T18:05:14Z",
                "updated_at":"2014-09-06T06:59:23Z",
                "abuse_reported":null,
                "delay":0,
                "followers":118574,
                "profile_banner":null,
                "profile_banner_background_color":null,
                "views":186419614,"language":"en"
            }
        }],
        "_total":1,
        "_links":{
            "self":"https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams?channel=starladder1&limit=25&offset=0",
            "next":"https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams?channel=starladder1&limit=25&offset=25",
            "featured":"https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/featured",
            "summary":"https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/summary",
            "followed":"https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/followed"
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Pedro GS
probably other API queries will give you more results than this "little" response. So you need to understand what you are getting back

Answer (score 0):

Here is code for you:

```
$hue = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/starladder1'));
echo "Name :" .$hue->display_name;
```

You just do wrong url to fetch